# How to get fixed size (especially the width) of the cell in the GridView?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a GridView that has different width of different cells in its Header. I want to get specific size of each cell since I have a scroll bar from left to right. 
What I have up to now is what the following:

[image]

And what I want is to have something like the following:
[image]

The style of the table is:

```
<style type="text/css">

        .fixedColumn .fixedTable td
        {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            background-color: #5097d1;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        .fixedHead td, .fixedFoot td
        {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            /*background-color: #5097d1;*/
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: normal;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #187BAF;
            width: 600px;
        }
        .fixedTable td
        {
            font-size: 10pt;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            padding: 5px;
            /*text-align: left;*/
            border: 1px solid #CEE7FF;
        }
    </style>
```

***EDIT:***
I used the following code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
         if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header) || (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow))
           {     
             foreach (TableCell c in e.Row.Cells){
                    c.Wrap=true; 

                    c.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
             }
           }
}
```

And the header are changed a little bit and I don't know why as shown below:
[image]

Comment: you cannot give each cell as 100%, give less percentage for each cell, and make sure that all cell sum of percentage is 100%

Answer (score 1):

Better option is use skin file of grdiview , that can help you. look at here for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx

Comment: I don't want to use skin. I want to keep what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  Gridview  RowDataBound method to specify the width of each cell.

```
protected void gridview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs)
{
  if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header) || (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow))
   {     
            e.Row.Cells[yourCellIndex].Wrap=true; 

           e.Row.Cells[yourCellIndex].Width = Unit.Percentage(% value);

   }
}
```

and you make sure that, total width of all cell should be equal to 100%, if you are using Unit.Percentage() method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx

Comment: it changed the width for the rows cells except for the headers. what I want is to set all the headers horizontally and to be fixed. I don't want to have on of the headers that consists of two lines or more. All the headers should be in one line.

Comment: @user1093651 check my edited post.. may this time will help.. as i added for Header also